# FXM showing 0 for the overall visits for external website

Tags: fxm

I have added an external website to FXM(sitecore 9.0.2), the overall visits is showing 0. Also the newly crated site is not showing in Experience Analytics filter drop down as well.

[image]

Also tried adding a domain configuration still no results shown.
[image]

Comment: Have you published your external website? Have you added script to your external site? https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/add-an-external-website-in-fxm.html

Comment: HI Peter, I followed the same document for set up. I have published and FXM script is added in the external site. I can view the external site from experience editor as well without any errors. Any thing else I need to check?